# How do I resize the edit menu drop down?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI drop down menu in a view. The drop down that appears when the menu is selected is too large. Does anyone know how to resize it? I tried adding a frame after } on the menu block but that doesn't result in any changes.

```
Menu("Distance") {
    Button("10mile", action: viewModel.placeOrder)
    Button("20mile", action: viewModel.adjustOrder)
    Button("40mile", action: viewModel.cancelOrder)
}
.offset(x: 28)
.foregroundColor(.gray)
```